# how to find the username of a user from database when email is given in django

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am creating a website where a banks loggs in with its username which is a code but i wanted that bank could log in with its first_name.

i am using default user model for registration.

but authenticate() function works only with username so what i wanted to do is that bank fill their name  and function finds the value of username with corrosponding name in the database and then use authenticate() function to log the bank in.

> **my login function in view.py**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        username = ????????
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active and has_role(user,Banker):
                auth_login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('business:dashboard'))
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Your account is not active")
                return render(request,'accounts/bank_login.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Invalid Username or Password")
            return render(request,'accounts/bank_login.html')
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('business:dashboard'))
        else:
            return render(request,'accounts/bank_login.html')
```

so please anybody could tell what should i write in that username to get the value of username from database

> **my models.py **

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth

# Create your models here.
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more complex than doing a simple query. Also, you cannot rule our that two users with the same first name will choose the same password. Here the first user found is taken

Something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

firstnameusers = User.objects.filter(first_name=name)
for usr in firstnameusers:
    if check_password(password, usr.password):
        username = usr.username
        break
```

Note that you will need to write some code to handle the case where a user is not found.

Answer (score 0):

> **I used this in my views.py file and it works perfectly**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = (request.POST.get('name')).upper()
        username = (get_user_model().objects.all().filter(first_name = name)).values("username")[0]["username"]
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```